# Sort by column that contains null values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd figure this would be an easy problem to solve, but I've been googling like crazy trying to find an answer and I'm just not getting one.

I want to sort the results based on a column that contains null values. SQL Server seems to thinks that's a bad idea. I've tried limiting them using `ISNULL`, `LIKE`, as well as a few other various methods to try to get this to work and it's just not happening.

```
SELECT c1
FROM t1
WHERE c1 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY c1 DESC
```

SQL Server gives me this error:
`The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.`

Like I said, I've been googling like crazy trying to find an answer to this simple problem and it's just not happening.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken SQL Server isn't complaining about the NULL values, it's complaining that it cannot sort a text, ntext or image data type.

Comment: To add to that comment check the section for limitations on the MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx If you cast it as a varchar you should be able to sort it no problem

Comment: I am assuming that it's `text/ntext` type. Instead of introducing `Order By` clause, why not it is originally `Varchar(max)` designed?

Comment: @PankajGarg I'm not sure, I didn't design this database. It makes no sense to me either, which is why I overlooked the obvious. lol. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

c1 is  text, ntext, or image

so as the error says you can't order by them

try casting the text/ntext to varchar(max) that should do it.

```
SELECT c1
FROM t1
WHERE c1 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY convert(varchar(max),c1) DESC
```

Comment: As John Nolan mentioned, text, ntext, or image are special because they are actually stored as lobs which makes them unsortable.  The conversion to varchar(max) (or nvarchar(max) if you are using ntext) should allow you to sort.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even notice that they stored this as a **text** value and not a **varchar**. I guess that's why I couldn't find an answer. :) I just assumed it was due to the column containing nulls.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY cast(c1 as varchar(max)) DESC
```

and consider switching the column `c1`'s type to `varchar(max)`.  `text` is an [obsolete data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx).

Comment: The size of each record of table is a performance parameter. Then why order by clause for `Varchar(max)`?

Comment: @PankajGarg: `varchar(max)` is variable length (hence the name varchar).  F.e. `cast('abc' as varchar(max))` takes up three bytes.

Comment: Yes. This is for just one cell. Are you aware of the reads corresponding to the query?

Answer (score 0):

I found something that says you can only sort varchar. Try this bit of code.

SELECT c1
FROM t1
WHERE c1 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY cast(c1 as varchar(MAX))

src:http://twogeeks.mindchronicles.com/?p=7

Comment: BUt why should I do order by for a column with 2GB size for each cell?